# Select displayed arguments of push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I get a push notification that looks like this:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "loc-key" : "localized_pn_text",
            "loc-args" : [ "France", "Frank"]
        },
        "sound" : "chime.aiff"
    },
    "acme" : "foo"
}
```

In my `Localizable.strings` I can now add a string with key `"localized_pn_text"` to localize the push notification.

Is there a way to order or select a specific parameter. For example, can I show `"Frank, you got a push notification"` as the **localised** text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can select the parameters with `%<parameter index starting with 1>$@`

For the example I can write this in the `Localizable.strings` file:
`"localized_pn_text" = "%2$@, you got a push notification"`

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. add `"localized_pn_text" = "%@, you got a push notification"` in your `Localizable.strings`, and then send only "Frank" as `"loc-args"` (`"loc-args" : [ "Frank"]`)
2. Implement a [Notification Service Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) to intercept the push notification and create its content programmatically, below an example:

```
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            handleContent(bestAttemptContent: bestAttemptContent)

            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            handleContent(bestAttemptContent: bestAttemptContent)

            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

    func handleContent(bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent) {
        if let data = bestAttemptContent.userInfo as? [String: Any], let aps = bestAttemptContent.userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any], let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String: Any] {
            if let locKey = alert["loc-key"] as? String, let locArgs = alert["loc-args"] as? [String] { 
                bestAttemptContent.body = //Uptaded notification text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add custom keys in the `dictionary` like,

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "loc-key" : "localized_pn_text",
            "loc-args" : [ "France", "Frank"]
        },
        "sound" : "chime.aiff"
    },
    "acme" : "foo",
    "customText": "Frank, you got a push notification"
}
```

Read the value of `customText` using,

```
if let customText = notification.request.content.userInfo["customText"] as? String {
    print(customText)
}
```

Comment: This is not what I mean, I want to show a localised push notification with only one of the params. `customText` would not be localised